# Can I stop server processing a POST request with abortController?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

**is abortController able to stop the server processing canceled request, or it just works on the client side to discard whatever response the server gives for the canceled request?**

```
const abortController = React.useRef\<AbortController | null\>(null);

const handleClick = async () => {
    if (abortController.current) {
      abortController.current.abort();
      return;
    }

    abortController.current = new AbortController();

    try {
      const { result } = await axiosApiPost(params, { signal: abortController.current.signal });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
};
```

I used abortController to discard duplicated POST request to server.
I have a 'import' button, and the button shows 1~2s loading until server responds with the result status.

However, I want to add 'cancel' button that stops previous import request if clicked while loading.
So I used abortController, but it does not work. I mean, the request is canceled as shown in devtool's network tab but still it's imported when the page refreshed.

I wonder is there an any way at client side to make server stop processing the post request.

Comment: You could send another request that will stop current operations

Comment: _"it just works on the client side to discard whatever response the server gives for the canceled request"_  this one

Comment: It depends on the server tech if it's able to receive a signal in your application, and it depends on your server code if you handle the abort.